# Ubuntu 19.04 teminal launcher from desktop changed to "Open in terminal"

Tags: gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, home-directory, desktop-icons, context-menu

After upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04, I noticed my terminals keep starting up in the Desktop folder instead of home.

Finally I realized, out of years of habit, I start up terminals by right-clicking the desktop background to get that pop-up menu and select *Open terminal*.

But now I see that it's been changed to *Open **in** terminal*, so I now understand *why* it's opening a terminal in `~/Desktop`.

For the record, launching a terminal using the sidebar (Ubuntu Dock) panel icon does still open a new window in the home directory.

But I like launching terminals from the menu, so this change is irritating.  Is there a config?

Comment: Don't know a solution, but most certainly the reason is the fundamental change of how desktop icons (and related stuffs) are handled in GNOME 3. Previously it was the Nautilus file-manager that used to handle desktop icons, now, since 19.10, an extension does the job.

Comment: Note: I'm only on 19.04, not 19.10.  Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped, I meant 19.04 instead of 19.10. The change occurred with 19.04. For reference, see this [OMG! Ubuntu article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/11/ubuntu-19-04-release-features) ("New Desktop Icons Extension" section).